# Is there scripts of QGIS core plugins available anywhere?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, qgis-2

Is there anywhere I can see the scripts of the Qgis core plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by "scripts" and what do you mean by "core plugins"? Do you just want the source code?

Comment: yeah I need the source codes. Core plugins means the plugins available along with the release of the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source code for QGIS is on Github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/

The plugins are at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/plugins

If you need to get source for a particular version of QGIS, its probably easiest to [download the relevant tarball](http://qgis.org/downloads/), although you could select from a branch. For example, for 2.6 it would be https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-2_6/src/plugins

Note the licensing conditions on the source code in the header.

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to know the source code of the toolbars say (add vector layer toolbar) is also available

Comment: You have the link to the whole source! Its all available.

Comment: I don't see the source code of any tools in QGIS instead I can only see the source code of core plugins in the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 2):

Just look on the github page at the source code https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins